# Images set from Assets get resized/rescalled?

Tags: android, imageview

.
  I am trying to display the images on imageview located in assets of my application.
Problem is that when i set images from assets folder, image size is getting smaller than actual image size.If i set Images by putting them in resources then they are properly displayed. as shown in following screen shots:

Images set from Resources:
[image]

Images set from Assets:
[image]

Red circled images are set from assets and other from resources.

I want that the images set from assets should not get shrinked. They should also look like the images set from resources.

Following is my code used to set images :

```
                try
                {

                    myimgview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    Drawable draw=Drawable.createFromStream(assetManager.open(drawableFolder+"/"+tmpArr[0]), null);
                    myimgview.setImageDrawable(draw);
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    LNLog.writeTOErrorToLog(e.getMessage());
                }
```

Following is the way to set image from resources:

```
                    try
                    {

                        myimgview.setImageDrawable(SecondActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(2130837505));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        LNLog.writeTOErrorToLog(e.getMessage());
                    }
```

So please ,
A. can anyone tell me how can i resolve this problem.
B. Why images scales defferently from Assets and resources.
Thankx in advance.

Comment: `Following is my code used to set images :` But that is only one way. You should post both ofcourse.

Comment: can you try without `myimgview.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`?

Comment: Yes @blackbelt , previously i tried without setAdjustViewBounds(true) but then also it does not work.

Comment: Set this property android:scaleType="fitXY" to your imageview

Comment: @RIT i set it but not worked.

Comment: First check it in sample app, then try it in this, it will work because I tested it